# AndroidStudio - Gradle Refresh Failed

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

I was using the up to date version of android studio to build my app for android. The gradle wrapper set up the gradle installation and the project was build without errors.

Eventually I started getting one error each time I restarted.

> Gradle: A problem occurred configuring project ':App'.
>
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':App:classpath'.
>   Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+.
>   Required by:
>   App:App:unspecified
>
> > org.slf4j.spi.LocationAwareLogger.log(Lorg/slf4j/Marker;Ljava/lang/String;ILjava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V

The issue could be fixed by executing gradlew again and builds went fine. But after the 0.3 android studio update and android plugin update to 0.6.+ I can't even execute gradlew anymore without getting this error message.

I tried uninstalling android studio with all its configuration files, deleted the .gradle folders in the project and home directory and even the .m2 repository. I can't even start a new android project, it fails with the same error, so there should be no issue with my build.grade

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.6.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 18
    buildToolsVersion "18.1.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 18
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'src/main/AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java']
            res.srcDirs = ['src/main/res']
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.0'
    compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.7.2'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem. I don't know what caused the bug, but its gone. Steps to fix:

- Backup and delete existing project
- Deinstalling android studio 0.3
- Deleting .gradle/ and .androidstudio/ in user directory
- Installing android studio 0.2.X
- Patching android studio to 0.2.9
- Reimporting code backup

Answer (score 1):

This is known issue http://tools.android.com/knownissues

The Android Gradle plugin 0.6.2 was published with incorrect dependencies. There isn't a way to delete it, so we have instead release 0.6.3 which fixes the problems. Just switch your version from 0.6.+ to 0.6.3, or **run gradlew with --refresh-dependencies** to force Gradle to look for an update.

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.6.+'
}
```

instead of

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.6.3'
}
```

Comment: Where do you put this?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the latest version of Gradle as the latest Android Studio needed 1.8. Also make sure that you have downloaded updates through the Android SDK that is bundled in Studio. `Tools-> Android-> SDK Manager`

You will need the latest Android Support Library

Comment: gradle got updated to 1.8 automaticly through gradlew after I changed the gradle-wrapper.properties. The SDK is in another directory but up-to-date. The Problem persists after the update 
         `Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':App:classpath'.
         Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.6.+.
         Required by:
         App:App:unspecified
     org.slf4j.spi.LocationAwareLogger.log(Lorg/slf4j/Marker;Ljava/lang/String;ILjava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V`

Comment: seems like you need to change the gradle version in your gradle wrapper. Or just chose to use the locally installed Gradle instead of using the wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue then I upgrade my react-native version :-

```
react-native upgrade
```

its works fine for me now

Comment: where do you put this?