# Problems importing/refreshing Gradle project in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I have updated Android Studio from version `.2.0` to `.3.1` and when I start Studio it displayed the following error message:

> "Problems importing/refreshing Gradle project 'Second':Unresolved
>   dependencies: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+ Search"

Comment: No image is shown and I believe you have no rep to input images so just paste its url to someone can input it to you.

Answer (score 5):

As per my answer on [AndroidStudio - Gradle Refresh Failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19481760/androidstudio-gradle-refresh-failed/19488876#19488876)

You probably need to update the Bundled Android SDK that comes with Studio:

```
Tools-> Android-> SDK Manager
```

I did a blog post about [Android Studio Gotchas](http://www.samael.me.uk/2013/10/android-studio-gotchas.html) which also mentions this.

For some reason they totally ignore any Android SDK you may have manually installed and use their own. So selecting the SDK through the IDE makes sure you use the correct one. You need to ensure you have the latest compatibility library.

You may also need to restart the IDE after updating. I did in any case, can't remember if it was essential.